# Powering a 12 Volt Air Pump to a 36 Volt Electric Forklift

Tags: batteries, electricity

I have a 12 Volt Air Pump (300 W) that I use to inflate products. Normally it is connected to a forklift battery with alligator clips and that's how we power it. We have had people ask how to use these pumps with their 36 volt Electric Forklift batteries.

Is it possible to do this? Do I need some sort of converter or reducer installed?

I have no experience in any sort of electrical wiring work, I am being asked questions I don't have the answers too and I am having trouble even being able to word the question correctly. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a DC to DC converter, with a 12v output, and an input range that includes 36v. It needs sufficient current output for 300W, so 300/12 = 25Amps.

Comment: @RudyMartinez the professional way to do it would be a product like the SD-500L-12, from RS, £160 including VAT. You can get cheaper hobby ones from fleaBay or spamazon, but no warranty, you'd need to box it, quality is questionable, etc etc ...

Comment: If possible could you link to one that would work? I'd have no problem getting one that costs a little more as long as it works and is covered. I am looking up that part number but see a few options. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Welcome to EESE but please note that direct shopping questions will result in fairly prompt closure of your question as per [site rules](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @RudyMartinez I'm not putting a link to the part in my answer, due to the site rules about recommending speciifc products. However, in my comment I've given you the manufacturer's part number down to the last digit and piece of punctuation, and the name of a supplier, RS, who lists it. If you can't use google, then I'm afraid this site is beyond you.